# JavaMail, postfix on mac - read timeout, mail command line works

Tags: email, timeout, jakarta-mail

I'm writing a spring mvc app and using JavaMail which is configured in my applicationContext.xml.

I've setup postfix and having it running on mac os.

I can send email via postfix using the mail command line program.

However, when I try to send email via JavaMail I get a read time out  exception.

Tried sending email via telnet as described here http://www.rdpslides.com/webresources/FAQ00035_Send_Email_via_Telnet.htm but the smtp doesn't respond at all. You can type in the commands but nothing ends up happening.

I don't know what is special about using the mail command line client but it works fine.

i.e. This works (matt is my local username):

```
$ date|mail -s testing matt
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">

    <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="port" value="25"/>
    <property name="protocol" value="smtp"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.timeout">2000</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.connectiontimeout">2000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try your command line test with "mail -v" and see if it gives any clues.
The mail command is probably fork/execing sendmail so it's not connecting
via locahost:25.  Check your postfix configuration; it sounds like you're
connecting with telnet but getting a timeout on the read, not the connection,
so I have no idea what postfix might be doing.